Adding a metadata such as location,geo-location-name,geo-location-latitude to an mp4 file using GStreamer Framework in cpp
I have the following GStreamer pipeline:
    gst_element_link_many(source, convert, overlay, encoder, parser, taginject, muxer, sink, NULL);
    where, encoder = x264enc
           parser = h264parse
           muxer = mp4mux
           sink = filesink

I am setting metadata tags in the taginject element like this:
    g_object_set(taginject, "tags", "title=Success,artist=xxxx,geo-location-name=yyyy", NULL);

The tags for title and artist are successfully added to the metadata, but tags like geo-location-name, geo-location-latitude, and some tags do not seem to be added.
Even when I inspect the file using a hex editor, I can only find the title and artist tags in the metadata. what could be causing this issue?
